# Scala Spark Dataframe - Sum for each row the content of Array[Double]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is my basic Dataframe:

```
root |-- user_id: string (nullable = true) 
     |-- review_id: string (nullable = true) 
     |-- review_influence: double (nullable = false)
```

The goal is to have the sum of review_influence for each user_id.  So I tried to aggregate the data and sum it up like this:

```
val review_influence_listDF = review_with_influenceDF
.groupBy("user_id")
.agg(collect_list("review_id") as("list_review_id"), collect_list("review_influence") as ("list_review_influence"))
.agg(sum($"list_review_influence"))
```

But I have this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'sum(`list_review_influence`)' due to data type mismatch: function sum requires numeric types, not ArrayType(DoubleType,true);;
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly sum the column in the `agg` function:

```
review_with_influenceDF
    .groupBy("user_id")
    .agg(collect_list($"review_id").as("list_review_id"), 
         sum($"review_influence").as("sum_review_influence"))
```